# Flask socketio room

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio

Found this boilerplate and was wondering of `join_room` is really required before you can emit messages to a room?

```
from flask import session
from flask_socketio import emit, join_room, leave_room
from .. import socketio


@socketio.on('joined', namespace='/chat')
def joined(message):
    """Sent by clients when they enter a room.
    A status message is broadcast to all people in the room."""
    room = session.get('room')
    join_room(room)
    emit('status', {'msg': session.get('name') + ' has entered the room.'}, room=room)


@socketio.on('text', namespace='/chat')
def text(message):
    """Sent by a client when the user entered a new message.
    The message is sent to all people in the room."""
    room = session.get('room')
    emit('message', {'msg': session.get('name') + ':' + message['msg']}, room=room)


@socketio.on('left', namespace='/chat')
def left(message):
    """Sent by clients when they leave a room.
    A status message is broadcast to all people in the room."""
    room = session.get('room')
    leave_room(room)
    emit('status', {'msg': session.get('name') + ' has left the room.'}, room=room)
```

Can't I just store the room in the session and send messages to the room?

```
@socketio.on('text', namespace='/chat')
def text(message):
    """Sent by a client when the user entered a new message.
    The message is sent to all people in the room."""
    room = session.get('room')
    emit('message', {'msg': session.get('name') + ':' + message['msg']}, room=room)
```

Comment: Yes, you can emit to a room without joining it. Did you find any problems doing that?

Comment: @Miguel I have not tried thank you for letting me know

Comment: @Miguel If we can emit to a room without joining, what would be the benefit of having 2 additional events that use join_room() and leave_room()?

Comment: @Nahua joining/leaving a room and emitting are completely independent operations, they are not related at all, so I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.